# RegEx - Match using symbols but don't replace them

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to use a symbols in a RegEx pattern to find matches, but I don't want them replaced. This is for class and namespace manipulation in C#.

For example:

> `MyNamespaceLib.EntityDataModelTests.TestsMyClassTests+MyInnerClassTests`

must be replaced as:

> `MyNamespaceLib.EntityDataModel.TestsMyClass+MyInnerClass`

(Note, only "Tests" is replace when it appears at the end of the namespace part, and not when it's part of the class/namespace name)

I've managed to get the first part right in finding the matches, but I'm battling to keep the symbols in the replaced match.

So far I have:

> `var input = "MyNamespaceLib.EntityDataModelTests.TestsMyClassTests+MyInnerClassTests";`
>
> `var output = Regex.Replace(input, "Tests[.+]|$", "");`

I've tried using a non-capturing group, but I suspect it's not meant for the way I'm trying to use it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So what you want to do is replace matches *not* followed by a `.` or a `+`? Use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
@"Tests(?![.+])"
```

Comment: No, the opposite, I'd like to replace matches that essentially end with a ".", "+" or end of line. But if the word "Tests" appears within a namespace or class name, then it mustn't be replaced.

Comment: @user1927385: `Tests(?![^.+])`, then.

Comment: Nice, that worked perfectly. I've never used lookaheads in Regex, so I'll go read up some more. Thanks minitech.

Comment: Thanks minitech, your answer solved my issue quickly.

Comment: Can also do `?=` for the positive lookahead (e.g. `Tests(?=[.+]`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [MatchEvaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx) overload of the Regex.Replace method, where the string to replace the match with is generated on the fly. I get the special simbol in a capturing group (and the first capturing group is always Group[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx) of the match), and replace the match with the value, like this:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"Tests([.+]|$)", m => m.Groups[1].Value);
```

Also, per minitech's comment, you can also use $1 for the first capturing group in the (string, string) overload of Regex.Replace, like:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"Tests([.+]|$)", "$1");
```

That said, a regex is often write-only code, so you can always do a dumb and simple replace:

```
var output = input.Replace("Tests+","").Replace("Tests.","") ...;
```

Comment: Yeah, it would work, I was trying to get it all done with one RegEx pattern. I'd do this last if I can't get it to work.

Comment: Yes, that is done with [this Regex.Replace overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx), I'll try to cook up an example in a minute.

Comment: If you want to replace something with the value of a group, you can do that inside a string: `Regex.Replace(..., "$1")`

Comment: Didn't know that, I'll update the answer. Anyway, I like lambdas :)